# Jade: Why && is compiled to &amp; when used in angularjs in Jade template?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, pug

I am using AngularJS inside the Jade templates with ExpressJS. In my form validation, I have the following line of code in jade template.

```
div(ng-show="form.username.$dirty && !signup_form.name.$focused")
```

When Jade template is rendered and HTML file is sent to client, above line is translated as follows.

```
<div ng-show="form.username.$dirty &amp;&amp; !signup_form.name.$focused" =>
```

I tried to replace `&&` in jade with `&amp;` but it translated to `&amp;amp;`. I tried put `\&\&` but it also did not work.

Kindly help.

Comment: Was this breaking something? The browser should treat them both identically.

Comment: It did not break anything. It just did not do what I wanted it to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
div(ng-show != "form.username.$dirty && !signup_form.name.$focused")
```

Using `!=` disables HTML-encoding in attributes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I spent more then 3 hours for searching this  simple solution!